# MVC web api:What is No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ( CORS Policy )

Tags: c#

No Access Control Allow Origin

When running api locally, it can't call the another localhost api. Why? It say CORS policy criteria does not match.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read [ask] and come back and edit your question. As it stands it is hard to give an answer without more detail of your problem and the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

Java script makes communication between 2 different servers difficult. If a request is complicated for example if it involves exchange of objects. Then it is blocked by the cors policy. You need an 'handshake' from the services. An OPTION type  http request will be sent. In response the web client must receive your new domain name in order 'handshake' to happen.

Comment: The OP is asking about MVC Web API and tagged the question as C# - at no point did they mention Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served.

A web page may freely embed cross-origin images, stylesheets, scripts, iframes, and videos. Certain "cross-domain" requests, notably Ajax requests, are forbidden by default by the same-origin security policy. CORS defines a way in which a browser and server can interact to determine whether it is safe to allow the cross-origin request. It allows for more freedom and functionality than purely same-origin requests, but is more secure than simply allowing all cross-origin requests.

The specification for CORS is included as part of the WHATWG's Fetch Living Standard. This specification describes how CORS is currently implemented in browsers. An earlier specification was published as a W3C Recommendation.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Framework that you use. Basically, that should be solved by putting some syntax that allow cross-origin request permission to the top of your code.
Also, if you run with IIS, just enable CORS module on your specific Web Application by adding it to web.config.

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```